# Cambiar todos los datos que hay en una columna dentro de una tabla en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas:

`id_opcion, id_catalogo,descripcion,valor,ordenamiento`

con lo siguientes datos:
`10445,12,COMENSALES,NULL,0`

Necesito cambiar los datos de la columna `id_catalogo` pero al ser demasiados y no estarlos cambiando uno por uno la pregunta es ¿existe algun método para cambiar solo los datos de esa columna?

Comment: respuesta a una pregunta con tan pocos detalles: "sí, existe un método". Ahora, para una respuesta específica, necesitamos información específica

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! por supuesto que existe!!! tuviste algun problema usandolo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer una opración de `UPDATE`, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE tu_tabla SET id_catalogo=nuevo_valor WHERE tu_condicion_de_modificacion;
```

Comment: Es correcto  muchas gracias por la ayuda ya realice asi y me sirvio